# Image file compression in java

Tags: java, image, javax.imageio

I'm trying to compress an image file(jpg) using `ImageIO`. my goal is to compress image to 30 kb or less. Below is the code i used to compress image. The code is working fine. But it is not compressing to 30 kb, even if i tried again with the compressed image. 
Then I try to scale the image. that time i got 30 kb file but quality is vet\y poor.
My file is an image of an application form. So I need the data to be readable.
Is ther any way i can do this with `ImageIO` or any other libraries.

```
    public void jpegCompression(File imageFile,String path,Integer flag) {

            try {
            File compressedImageFile = new File(path+flag+"_"+imageFile.getName());

            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(imageFile);
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(compressedImageFile);

            float quality = 0.1f;

            // create a BufferedImage as the result of decoding the supplied InputStream
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(is);

            // get all image writers for JPG format
            Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");

            if (!writers.hasNext())
                throw new IllegalStateException("No writers found");

            ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter) writers.next();
            ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(os);
            writer.setOutput(ios);

            ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();

            // compress to a given quality
            param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
            param.setCompressionQuality(quality);

            // appends a complete image stream containing a single image and
            //associated stream and image metadata and thumbnails to the output
            writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param);

            // close all streams
            is.close();
            os.close();
            ios.close();
            writer.dispose();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: If you don't reach 30kb when using quality = 0.1 (10%) then your image is simply too large and too much content. Java can't do magic. The ImageIO classes are not perfectly optimized but I doubt that other libraries will compress much better with the same quality. The JPEG image format just limits what you can get. I would test your sample images with [Google Guetzli compressor](https://github.com/google/guetzli) or any other highly optimized JPEG compressor - if you don't reach 30KB then it just can't be done.

Comment: _"My file is an image of an application form"_ Do you mean a photo of a physical (paper) form, or a screenshot of a digital form? If it's the latter case, are you sure that PNG wouldn't be a more suitable compressor?

Comment: It's a simple trade-off between the size and the quality. If 30kb is a hard requirement, then some combination of scaling the image down and compression quality should do the job.

Comment: @Michael Yes, its a photo of a paper form. This image is compressing for sending to a service provider. There requirement is jpeg.

Comment: @Robert i need to use it in a spring web application. I think Guetzil is not apt for integrating in java. Correct me if i'm wrong. I'm copressing a 3Mb image. I i do both scaling and compressing, then i got 30kb, but image quality is poor.

Comment: I said you should use Guetzil to test if at all the image can be compressed to 30kb and if it works you should get the best possible quality from it. I never said that you should use from within Java, just use it for test on the command-line!

Comment: If your paper form is black/white you could possibly get smaller file sizes by converting to grayscale, and write JPEGs with only one channel.